# CodeIgniter Join with Multiple where clause

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am new to PHP, I am using this query to get the number of floors in inventory, and it's working fine :

```php
$data['Floors'] = $this->db
    ->get_where('tblcustomfieldsvalues', ['fieldid' => 75, 'fieldto' => 'inventory', 'value' => 'Floor'])
    ->num_rows();
```

And I am using this query to get the number of exclusive inventories, and its also working fine:

```php
$data['total_leads_exc'] = $this->db
    ->from('tblinventory_status')
    ->where('id',10)
    ->get()
    ->num_rows();
```

Now I want to get the number of exclusive floors in inventory, where I think I need to join both queries so I am using the Join query like this:

```sql
SELECT tblnleads.name FROM tblnleads 
    LEFT JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues
        ON tblcustomfieldsvalues.id = tblnleads.id
    WHERE tblnleads.status = '10'
        AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid = '61'
        AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldto = 'inventory'
        AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.value = 'Floors';
```

But I am not getting the results.

Comment: usually when you want to chekc mulitple results you have the first like you have and the rest is an `EXISTIS (SELECT 1 FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues t1  WHERE tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid = '61' AND t1.id = tblcustomfieldsvalues.id)` and so on

Comment: If there is no record, then there is no record according to your condition. Check clause 

For understanding, show some entries with tblnleads.status = '10' and tblcustomfieldsvalues.id = tblnleads.id

Comment: It will be better you have posted table data and what the output you are getting for join query

Comment: show us how your DB relationship looks like?